# How to tell BeautifulSoup to extract the content of a specific tag as text? (without touching it)

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, beautifulsoup

I need to parse an html document which contains "code" tags

I'm getting the code blocks like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(content))
code_blocks = soup.findAll('code')
```

The problem is, if i have a code tag like this:

```
<code class="csharp">
    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
</code>
```

BeautifulSoup forse the closing of nested tags and transform the code block into:

```
<code class="csharp">
    List<person> persons = new List</person><person>();
    </person>
</code>
```

is there any way to extract the content of the code tags as text with BeautifulSoup without letting it fix what IT thinks are html markup errors?

Comment: Well, it *is* errenous markup. The angle brackets should be escaped with entities (&lt;...&gt;).

Comment: Yes, that is my actual solution, but I just don't like to have all my code snippets full of &lt; and &gt; everywhere. i'd like to find a cleaner way, not forcing me to replace all of the snippet everytime i have to post on my blog..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the code tag to the QUOTE_TAGS dictionary.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

content = "<code class='csharp'>List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();</code>"

BeautifulSoup.QUOTE_TAGS['code'] = None
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(content))
code_blocks = soup.findAll('code')
```

Output:

```
[<code class="csharp"> List<Person> persons = new List<Person>(); </code>]
```

Comment: Thanks, you are my hero! I'd give +1000 if I could!

Comment: And how do we extract the code rather than the HTML?