# Extract tag contents as text (QUOTE_TAGS equivalent) in BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup 3 has the nice feature that it will not try to interpret the contents of a `<textarea>` tag as html - it quotes it as text instead. This behavior can be had for other tags by modifying the `QUOTE_TAGS` attribute. Here's [an illustration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922969/how-to-tell-beautifulsoup-to-extract-the-content-of-a-specific-tag-as-text-wit) of how this can be useful.

In BeautifulSoup 4, there is no `QUOTE_TAGS` attribute, and I see no way to get the same functionality without subclassing `html.parser` myself. Am I missing something? How would you solve the problem linked above using BS4?

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup 4 doesn't have QUOTE_TAGS because it has no parser of its own: it relies on external parsers. Different parsers handle the same markup differently, and you've discovered one of these differences.

The lxml parser and Python's built-in html.parser both treat the contents of a `<textarea>` as HTML markup. The html5lib parser treats the contents of a `<textarea>` as raw data. Telling Beautiful Soup to use html5lib will give you the result you want:

```
BeautifulSoup(markup, "html5lib")
```

You'll need to install html5lib, of course.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try it and indeed html5lib behaves much more similarly to the bs3 parser in this respect. Thank you for this answer!